# what is the best approach to learning java

Tags: java

I originally had a bunch of code up here but now that I am somewhat more familiar with the world of programming (no expert by any means), I would like to know from a community's perspective, the best approach to learning java the practical way, I have since (the original post) taken formal classes in C and C++, but would like to give java another chance. I now know how to understand the java docs (at least somewhat), so that's not what I am asking, but rather what are some stepping stones or hurdles to progressively over come when learning java or any new language for that matter?

Comment: Kindly tell if the problem still persists. Or what were you missing.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing this    `Passenger p = new Passenger();`.

But I cannot see any class named `Passenger` in your code. Correct the class name.

Your code is really incomplete. `survivalToll()` method is also not defined.

Variable `survivor` not declared. Many more are there.

You are confused with the constructor as method. I think you code chunk should be replaced by

```
class Passenger {


    //private String[] lastNames;
    private Scanner scan;
    private String path;

    private ArrayList<String[]> passengerList;

    public Passenger(String filePath) {
        this.path = filePath;
        this.passengerList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        this.readFile();
    }}
```

Comment: Please look at the code carefully before downvoting. And let me know if you don't find a function named `Passenger`. There is a function named Passenger and the error clearly says that the return type is missing. Observe!!

Comment: What makes you think that he has not created a class named `Passenger` ?. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Passenger p = new Passenger(args[0]); Is this the way to invoke any function named "Passenger". I guess not !

Comment: Also, you can see that all his method names are starting from a lowercase char which is the right way, and this is not the case with Passenger.

Comment: Take a look. There is a function in the code. I am not talking about the object creation part. Observe the end portion of the code.

Comment: He has confused the method with the Constructor.

Comment: Did you see the function I am talking about?. Can you see that the return type is missing? Your conclusion seems to be absurd.

Comment: I think you should first degub the code in your local.

Comment: Listen. Your answer is based on an assumption. Can you read the error which is given by the OP? ` return type required in line 100 public Passenger(String filePath) ` What is this suppose to mean? It means that the return type is missing and it is missing indeed. What on earth makes you think that he has not created another class named Passenger?

Comment: I have also checked it by adding a return type. As I said, you should debug it first before blindly commenting.

Comment: Come on. How would you debug it before the OP provides you the code of the missing class Passenger? If you simply execute it by adding return type, it will give an error. The OP might have posted the class which is giving an error. He has not provided class Passenger.

Comment: He has given the wrong class name TestTitanic, it should be Passenger. As you can also see methods int getTotalPass(), float getPassWhoDied() defined in TestTitanic but invoked by Passenger object.

Comment: I understand. See I have no personal grudge against you to oppose your ideas. All I am saying is that you are making an assumption. Passengef could be a subclass of TestTitanic. Subclass objects can invoke superclass functions. There are wide range of possibilities. We must try to answer based on the question asked. You could also add extra if you find a flaw or misconception. The primary problem here would be the missing return type. The OP is free to post anothef question if he is getting a problem after correcting the current one.